# Delete a value from array with jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

```
<div id="values">10 67 87 100 56</div>

<div id="#val1">87</div>
```

How can I delete 87 value from array when click the #val1 with jquery?

Comment: Show your code with the array please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of doing it could be like this:

```
​$(function​ () {
    $("#val1").click(function() {
        var arr = $("#values").text().split(" "); // Create an array of the values
        var toRemove = $(this).text(); // Get the value to remove

        // Remove the value
        arr = $.grep(arr, function(value) {
            return value != toRemove;
        });

        // Add the new array back as text (without the removed value)
        $("#values").text(arr.join(" "));
    });
});​
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VFZ2b/)

Answer (score 2):

try something like

```
var y = [10, 67, 87 ,100 ,56] //or $("#values").text().split(' ');
var removeItem = 67;

y = jQuery.grep(y, function(value) {
  return value != removeItem;
});
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uqyXb/)

Answer (score 2):

Well you are not really talking about an array here. Just some textual values within a `<div>` element.

What you could do is create an array from the existing values like this -

```
var selection = $("#val1").text();
var divValues = $("#values").text().split(' ');
```

Then assemble a new array consisting solely of values that do not match the selected value (in this case `87`).

```
var newValues = [];
$.each(divValues,function(index,value){
  if (value != selection){
    newValues.push(value);
  }
});
```

Now we join the array values back together to get back to the textual content we extracted earlier.

```
$("#values").text(newValues.join(' '));
```

Comment: The first example could be a little problematic, I'm thinking if one of the values would be 187, 287, etc...

Comment: @mar - very, very true... I removed that suggestion. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

if `#values` contains array like data which is separated by space then you can do something like :

```
 $('#val').click(function () {
            var delVal = $("#val").text();
            var arr = $("#values").text().split(' ');
            $("#values").html("");
            for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] != delVal)
                    $("#values").append(arr[i] + " ");
            }
        });
```

**check this in jsFiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/Milian/buNaM/